# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time. When trying to send email using SmtpClient()

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, mailkit

I am trying to send confirm email address using .NET 6 MailKit. But getting the following error

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(short)
> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ValueTaskSourceAsTask..cctor.AnonymousMethod__4_0(object)

here is my send email method code

```
private void Send(MimeMessage mailMessage)
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(_emailConfig.SmtpServer, _emailConfig.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                    client.Authenticate(_emailConfig.UserName, _emailConfig.Password);
                    client.Send(mailMessage);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //log an error message or throw an exception or both.
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                    client.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }


"EmailConfiguration": {
    "From": "online.tapthat@gmail.com",
    "SmtpServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 587,
    "Username": "online.tapthat@gmail.com",
    "Password": "********!"
  }
```

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

This means that your network connection is timing out.

Catch the exception and then try reconnecting and sending again.